# Will this onCreate() method always run after Foo() constructor?

Tags: java, concurrency

I suppose this code is wrong, because the jvm can choose to run `onCreate()` before finishing constructor.

So, how can I ensure that `onCreate()`will always be executed, by another thread, when `Foo()`constructor is finished?

```
public class Foo{
    public Foo(){
        synchronized (this) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                synchronized (Foo.this) {
                    onCreate();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a static factory method:

```
public class Foo {
  // Private constructor forces instances to be created using factory method.
  private Foo() {}

  protected void onCreate() {}

  static Foo newInstance() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    new Thread(foo::onCreate).start();
    return foo;
  }
}
```